# NHibernate HiLo as long

Tags: nhibernate, long-integer, hilo

I will have a table with more than 7 billion rows so I need long for primary key. How to specify the HiLo to use In64 instead of int?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type="int64"` or just declare your Id property as `long` and NH will pick it up.

Comment: Yep, this does not work in SQL Lite. It created integer pk field

Comment: Check http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. "INTEGER" can be up to 8 bytes (64 bits) depending on the value, so you're fine.